# I want to install a second bathroom ehaust fan

Tags: electrical

I have a house built in 1995/6 (in MI) that has 2 full baths.  Both bathrooms already have an exhaust fan over the toilet.  I want to add a second exhaust fan to each bathroom, placed directly over the shower.  It's my understanding that this is allowed if the fan is GFCI protected.  Since the bathrooms already have GFCI protected outlets, and since the fans draw about 11W (100mA), would I be allowed to tap into that GFCI protected outlet circuit for these additional fans?  Or, would I need a dedicated circuit for the fans with a GFCI breaker?  Thanks?

Comment: Is there something unique about the shower that isolates it from the rest of the bathroom? Most people would just install a more powerful fan…

Comment: There is a reason why we don't put fans above the shower...   They are noisy and no one wants to hear it that close every shower, if you are taking a hot shower and need a fan you don't want the fan sucking the hotness from that zone immediately, and lastly these fans have metal and will rust if they are getting drip fog type of humidity which they would get above a shower